# Can Not read an URL for XML traversal, only locally

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, vbscript

I'm trying the XML of an url, but it doesn't seem to work.  it only works if i were to read it in from a local file.

the webpage i'm trying to read is: http://na.lolesports.com/api/standings?tournament=7

thank you very much for any help

```
Set xmlObject = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
'urlPath = "na.lolesports.com/api/standings?tournament=7/standings.xml"
'urlPath = "na.lolesports.com/api/standings?tournament=7"
'urlPath = "C:\Trio Scripts\standings.xml"
xmlObject.load(urlPath)

if (not isNull(xmlObject)) then 

set nodes = xmlObject.selectNodes("//team_title")
for i = 0 to (nodes.length - 1)
    msgbox(nodes(i).nodeName & " - " & nodes(i).text)
next
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet:

```
  Dim sUrl     : sUrl         = "http://na.lolesports.com/api/standings?tournament=7"
' Dim sUrl     : sUrl         = "na.lolesports.com/api/standings?tournament=7"
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.load sUrl

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     WScript.Echo "ok"
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

can be used to prove that the prefix "http://" is part of the Url and necessary.

(There are reasons for **all** the other differences between your and my code.)

Comment: it worked!!!!!!!  if possible, just for knowledge reasons, can you maybe explain how or why you did it that way?

Comment: oh and forgot to mention that i did put the "http://" part in my code before and that didn't work.. but your code did!